# Commands in bash don't work when translated to Python

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have this commands in bash:

```
ACTIVE_MGMT_1=ssh -n ${MGMT_IP_1} ". .bash_profile; xms sho proc TRAF.*" 2>/dev/null |egrep " A " |awk '/TRAF/{print $1}' |cut -d "." -f2;
```

I was trying to do it in Python like this:

```
active_mgmgt_1 = os.popen("""ssh -n MGMT_IP_1 ". .bash_profile; xms sho proc TRAF.*" 2>/dev/null |egrep " A " |awk '/TRAF/{print $1}' |cut -d "." -f2""") ACTIVE_MGMT_1 = active_mgmgt_1.read().replace('\n', '')
```

It doesn't work; any advice please?

Comment: Sure. [Try the docs.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)

Comment: try sourcing your `.bash_profile` first and see if that helps

Comment: Please review your `bash` command line first; it looks to me as though it runs a command `-n` with the environment variable `ACTIVE_MGMT_1` set to the value `ssh` — which doesn't seem as plausible as all that. Then you can start working out what the Python should look like.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very descriptive...

Answer (score 0):

Your popen call needs be set to communicate via a pipe.

Also stop trying to put everything on one line - python doesn't require it and places a lot of empasis on *readable* code.

I would strongly suggest doing the string processing in python rather than egrep, (use find or re in python), awk (find or egrep) and cut (string split).

It is also recommended to use subprocess.Popen rather than os.popen functions.  There is a suggestion to use shlex.spilt to clear up this sort of issue.

### untested code

```
import subprocess
import re
import os

MGMT_IP_1 = os.getenv('MGMT_IP_1')
sp = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ssh', '-n', MGMT_IP_1, '. .bash_profile; xms sho proc TRAF.*'],
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=None)
(result, outtext) = sp.communicate()
# Proceed to process outtext from here using re, find and split
# to the equivalent of egrep " A " |awk '/TRAF/{print $1}' |cut -d "." -f2;
```

Comment: when I'm writting this line sp = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ssh', '-n', MGMT_IP_1, '. .bash_profile; xms sho proc TRAF.*'],
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=None) i got this message:  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'PIPE' is not defined where i need to defined pipe?

Comment: >>> MGMT_IP_1 = os.getenv('MGMT_IP_1')
>>> sp = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-n', MGMT_IP_1, '. .bash_profile; xms sho proc TRAF.*'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
why i got this error?

Comment: What is `MGMT_IP_1` if it is not a string including if it start with a number you may need to use `MGMT_IP_1 = '%s' % (os.getenv('MGMT_IP_1'))`

Comment: mgmt_ip_1 = os.popen("awk -F ':' '{print $2}' /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf")
  MGMT_IP_1 = mgmt_ip_1.read().replace('\n', '') this what MGMT_IP_1 include

Comment: That tells me where you are getting it from not what it is!

Comment: it is IP address,  mgmt_ip_1 = os.popen("awk -F ':' '{print $2}' /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf") MGMT_IP_1 = mgmt_ip_1.read().replace('\n', '')  after i will run this i will get the ip address